# Conflict between TikZ package and memoir package - all packages updated

Tags: tikz-pgf, memoir, incompatibility

I am getting an error when I run memoir with the tikz package.  I updated my TexLive distribution to the 2012 version so there should be no conflicting version problems.  Memoir and tikz are both in my 2012 texlive path but the log file shows some odd dates.  I pared everything down to the simplest example I could make and the error still remains.  I am running TexShop on OS X and have tried typesetting both as Pdflatex and Tex+DVI.

Here's the minimum working example.  If I comment out \usepackage{tikz} it works fine if I leave it in it spots out an error (listed below).  The log file, due to its length, can be found [here](http://quantummoxie.wordpress.com/log-file/).

```
\documentclass[]{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\mainmatter
Test

\backmatter

\end{document}
```

The error I get is this:

```
...
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg))
! Extra \endcsname.
\@namelet ...fter \endcsname \csname #2\endcsname 

l.14
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated as I am attempting to write some lecture notes up for a class that begins soon.  Thanks!

Comment: I get no problems with your code but in the log file I see that you are using babel and maybe other things. So the best would be deleting the aux file and trying again. If you include `\listfiles` in your preamble it will show you the version info of each package. I have xcolor 2.11 and PGF/TikZ 2.10.

Comment: I just trashed my aux files and am still getting the error.  Potentially dumb question: does the version info show up in the log?  Because adding `\listfiles` didn't seem to change anything in any of the output.

Comment: Indeed the version infos show up in the log file.

Comment: Hmm.  Well, they did regardless of whether or not I included `\listfiles` in my preamble.  At any rate, the output in the log file looks exactly the same.  PGF is 2.10.  For whatever reason it's not showing a version for xcolor.  Incidentally, before doing all this, I had reinstalled xcolor last night in an effort to solve the problem (before updating my entire TexLive distribution in pure frustration).

Comment: If you simply go past all of the errors, do you get a file list in the `.log`? If so, can you edit it in.

Comment: The log I posted at the above link is the entire file - absolutely everything.  Your comment has me worried that there is a deeper problem here...

Comment: Sorry, the log as posted has no reference to `color.cfg`

Comment: I think there is indeed a problem with `xcolor` installation. You can search for manual installation for TL 2012 here too by searching on the main site. As @JosephWright comments, you can run the compilation from a command window and pass the errors until they get exhausted then you should have a log file even though the compilation is finished with errors.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it was odd that the log didn't include anything about color.cfg.  For some reason the saved log file is not the same thing as what shows up in the compiler window in TexShop.
Anyway, changing xcolor to a more recent version worked today so apparently the steps to solve the problem were to update both texlive and xcolor (though I had thought the latter was included with the former).  Thanks for the assistance everyone!

Comment: On that basis, this looks 'too localized' (there must have been some version issue on your machine).

Comment: Probably, though a closed question with a similar problem is what drew me here.  I think this may be a more common occurrence that at first it appears.